# How to get Flash movie's frames per second property in c++ builder

Tags: flash, actionscript, c++builder

I am working with ShockWave flash ActiveX in c++ builder 2010 IDE and my program show ads (swf files) that will be loaded by .ini file that I add the path to each movie. When  the number ads increased I have decided to write a method in c++ builder to play each swf movie consequently.
  As different swf movies have different number of frames, duration, and speed (FPS) I am going to create a method that track all swf information and will control playing swf file via TTimer.

As I said I have my.ini file

```
ads1=C:\1.swf
ads2=c:\2.swf
ads3=c:\3.swf
```

and so on

and my function looks like the following code..

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PlaySwfFile(TShockwaveFlash *fObj, AnsiString movPath)
{
    int totFrames,framesPerSec;
    fObj->Movie=movPath;
    totFrames=fObj->TotalFrames;
//  framesPerSec=fObj->




    delete fObj;

}
```

For now I am not able to get FramesPerSecond property!!!

How to get this property in C++ builder 2010??????
How to find out how long the movie will be played (in seconds) in order to set timers interval???

Answer (score 2):

The following code parses SWF header but in php

```
<?PHP 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SWF HEADER - version 1.0
// Small utility class to determine basic data from a SWF file header
// Does not need any php-flash extension, based on raw binary data reading
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//  SWFHEADER CLASS - PHP SWF header parser
//  Copyright (C) 2004  Carlos Falo Hervбs
//
//  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
//  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
//  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
//  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
//  Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
//  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
//  Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

class swfheader {

    var $debug ;                // Output DEBUG info
    var $fname ;                // SWF file analyzed
    var $magic ;                // Magic in a SWF file (FWS or CWS)
    var $compressed ;       // Flag to indicate a compressed file (CWS)
    var $version ;          // Flash version
    var $size ;                 // Uncompressed file size (in bytes)
    var $width ;                // Flash movie native width
    var $height ;               // Flash movie native height
    var $valid ;                // Valid SWF file
    var $fps ;                  // Flash movie native frame-rate
    var $frames ;               // Flash movie total frames

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    // swfheader($debug) :  Constructor, basically does nothing but initilize 
    //                                          debug and data fields
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    function swfheader($debug = false) {
        $this->debug = $debug ;
        $this->init() ;
      }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    // init() : initialize the data fields to "empty" values
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    function init() {
        $this->valid            = false ;
        $this->fname          = "" ;
        $this->magic            = "" ;
        $this->compressed = false ;
        $this->version      = 0 ;
        $this->width            = 0 ;
        $this->height           = 0 ;
        $this->size             = 0 ;
        $this->frames           = 0 ;
        $this->fps[]            = Array() ;
        if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Data values initialized<br>" ;
      }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // loadswf($filename) : loads $filename and stores data from it's header
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    function loadswf($filename) {
        $this->fname = $filename ;
        $fp = @fopen($filename,"rb") ;
        if ($fp) {
            if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Opened " . $this->fname . "<br>" ;
            // Read MAGIC FIELD
            $this->magic = fread($fp,3) ;
            if ($this->magic!="FWS" && $this->magic!="CWS") {
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: " . $this->fname . " is not a valid/supported SWF file<br>" ;
                $this->valid =  0 ;
            } else {
                // Compression
                if (substr($this->magic,0,1)=="C") $this->compressed = true ;
                else $this->compressed = false ;
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Read MAGIC signature: " . $this->magic . "<br>" ;
                // Version
                $this->version = ord(fread($fp,1)) ;
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Read VERSION: " . $this->version . "<br>" ;
                // Size
                $lg = 0 ;
                // 4 LSB-MSB
                for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
                    $t = ord(fread($fp,1)) ;
                    if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: " . ($t<<(8*$i)) . "<br>" ;
                    $lg += ($t<<(8*$i)) ;
                    }
                $this->size = $lg ;
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Total SIZE: " . $this->size . "<br>" ;
                // RECT... we will "simulate" a stream from now on... read remaining file
                $buffer = fread($fp,$this->size) ;
                if ($this->compressed) {
                    // First decompress GZ stream
                    $buffer = gzuncompress($buffer,$this->size) ;
                    }
                $b          = ord(substr($buffer,0,1)) ;
                $buffer = substr($buffer,1) ;
                $cbyte  = $b ;
                $bits   = $b>>3 ;
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: RECT field size: " . $bits . " bits<br>" ;
                $cval   = "" ;
                // Current byte
                $cbyte &= 7 ;
                $cbyte<<= 5 ;
                // Current bit (first byte starts off already shifted)
                $cbit   = 2 ;
                // Must get all 4 values in the RECT
                for ($vals=0;$vals<4;$vals++) {
                    $bitcount = 0 ;
                    while ($bitcount<$bits) {
                        if ($cbyte&128) {
                            $cval .= "1" ;
                        } else {
                            $cval.="0" ;
                            }
                        $cbyte<<=1 ;
                        $cbyte &= 255 ;
                        $cbit-- ;
                        $bitcount++ ;
                        // We will be needing a new byte if we run out of bits
                        if ($cbit<0) {
                            $cbyte  = ord(substr($buffer,0,1)) ;
                            $buffer = substr($buffer,1) ;
                            $cbit = 7 ;
                            }
                      }
                    // O.k. full value stored... calculate
                    $c      = 1 ;
                    $val    = 0 ;
                    // Reverse string to allow for SUM(2^n*$atom)
                    if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: RECT binary value: " . $cval  ;
                    $tval = strrev($cval) ;
                    for ($n=0;$n<strlen($tval);$n++) {
                        $atom = substr($tval,$n,1) ;
                        if ($atom=="1") $val+=$c ;
                        // 2^n
                        $c*=2 ;
                      }
                    // TWIPS to PIXELS
                    $val/=20 ;
                    if ($this->debug) echo " (" . $val . ")<br>" ;
                    switch ($vals) {
                        case 0:
                            // tmp value
                            $this->width = $val ;
                        break ;
                        case 1:
                            $this->width = $val - $this->width ;
                        break ;
                        case 2:
                            // tmp value
                            $this->height = $val ;
                        break ;
                        case 3:
                            $this->height = $val - $this->height ;
                        break ;
                      }
                    $cval = "" ;
                  }
                // Frame rate
                $this->fps = Array() ;
                for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
                    $t          = ord(substr($buffer,0,1)) ;
                    $buffer = substr($buffer,1) ;
                    $this->fps[] = $t ;
                    }
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Frame rate: " . $this->fps[1] . "." . $this->fps[0] . "<br>" ;
                // Frames
                $this->frames = 0 ;
                for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
                    $t          = ord(substr($buffer,0,1)) ;
                    $buffer = substr($buffer,1) ;
                    $this->frames += ($t<<(8*$i)) ;
                    }
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Frames: " . $this->frames . "<br>" ;
                fclose($fp) ;
                if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Finished processing " . $this->fname . "<br>" ;
                $this->valid =  1 ;
            }
        } else {
            $this->valid = 0 ;
            if ($this->debug) echo "DEBUG: Failed to open " . $this->fname . "<br>" ;
          }
        return $this->valid ;
      }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    // show() : report to screen all the header info
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    function show() {
      if ($this->valid) {
            // FNAME
            echo "<b>FILE: " . $this->fname . "</b><br>" ;
            // Magic
            echo "<b>MAGIC:</b> " . $this->magic ;
            if ($this->compressed) echo " (COMPRESSED)" ;
            echo "<br>" ;
            // Version
            echo "<b>VERSION:</b> " . $this->version . "<br>" ;
            // Size
            echo "<b>SIZE:</b> " . $this->size . " bytes <br>" ;
            // FRAMESIZE
            echo "<b>WIDHT:</B> " . $this->width . "<br>";
            echo "<b>HEIGHT:</B> " . $this->height . "<br>" ;
            // FPS
            echo "<b>FPS:</b> " . $this->fps[1] . "." . $this->fps[0] . " Frames/s <br>" ;
            // FRAMES
            echo "<b>FRAMES:</b> " . $this->frames . " FRAME <br>" ;
        } else {
            if (file_exists($this->fname))
                echo $this->fname . "is not a valid SWF file<br>" ;
            else
                if ($this->fname=="")
                    echo "SWFHEADER->SHOW : No file loaded<br>" ;
                else
                    echo "SWFHEDAR->SHOW : " . $this->fname . "was not found<br>" ;
          }
      }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // display($trans) : just echo <OBJECT>/<EMBED> tags for the parsed file, if
    //                                   trans is set, WMODE is set to transparent
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    function display($trans = false, $qlty = "high", $bgcolor = "#ffffff", $name = "") {

        $endl = chr(13) ;

        if ($this->valid) {
          if ($name=="") $name = substr($this->fname,0,strrpos($this->fname,".")) ;
            echo '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=' . $this->version . ',0,0,0" width="' . $this->width . '" height="' . $this->height . '" id="' . $name . '" align="middle">' . $endl ;
            echo '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />' . $endl ;
            if ($trans) {
                echo '<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />' . $endl ;
              }
            echo '<param name="movie" value="' . $this->fname . '" />' . $endl ;
            echo '<param name="quality" value="' . $qlty . '" />' . $endl ;
            echo '<param name="bgcolor" value="' . $bgcolor .'" />' . $endl ;
            echo '<embed src="' . $this->fname . '" ';
            if ($trans) echo 'wmode="transparent" ' ;
            echo 'quality="' . $qlty . '" bgcolor="' . $bgcolor . '" width="' . $this->width . '" height="' . $this->height . '" name="' . $name . '" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />' . $endl ;
            echo '</object>' . $endl ;
        } else {
            if ($this->debug) {
              if ($this->fname=="") {
                    echo "SWFHEADER->DISPLAY : No loaded file in the object<br>" ;
                } else {
                    if (file_exists($this->fname)) {
                        echo "SWFHEADER->DISPLAY : " . $this->fname . " is not a valid SWF file<br>" ;
                    } else {
                        echo "SWFHEADER->DISPLAY : " . $this->fname . " was not found<br>" ;
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
    }
}
?>
```

Test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>SWF header info</title>
</head>
<body>
<? require ("swfheader.class.php") ;?>
<?
// Create a new SWF header object with debug info, open with
// disabled debug (false) for silent processing
$swf = new swfheader(true) ;
// Open the swf file...
// Replace filename accordingly to your test environment...
$swf->loadswf("test.swf") ;
// Show data as a block... you can also access data within the object
$swf->show() ;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get frames per second and total number of frames from SWF header. See Chapter 2 of [specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf). If your SWF's aren't script controlled, this should give accurate info.

Comment: That's I need to open swf in binary mode, read necessary bytes and convert them to .. right?

Comment: Yes, read bytes and parse them into structures as described in spec. RECT can be tricky, but I've seen examples how to parse it (in ActionScript, but they can be translated to C++ as well).